# Declaration of variable, simple linked list

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
   char name[30];
   int age;
   struct node *next;
} *list_head,*neos;


main()
{
}

void add_node_to_the_list(char data1[],int data2)
{
     neos=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     strcpy(neos->name,data1);
     age=data2;
     neos->next=list_head;
     list_head=neos;
}

void display_list()
{
     struct node *p;
     p=list_head;
     while(p!=NULL)
     {
         puts(p->name);
         printf("%d\n",age);
         p=p->next;
     }
}
```

When I compile this code I get an error because I haven't declare the "age" variable, although I have done that inside the struct node, outside the main function. Why?

Comment: ... and please format your code correctly.

Comment: oh yes,stupid mistake,thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
       char name[30];
       int age;
       struct node *next;
       }*list_head,*neos;







main()
{
      }
void add_node_to_the_list(char data1[],int data2)/*Ç óõíáñôçóç áõôç ðñïóèåôåé êïìâï óôç ëéóôá*/
{
     neos=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     strcpy(neos->name,data1);
     neos->age=data2; //the correction is made here
     neos->next=list_head;
     list_head=neos;
     }
void display_list()
{
     struct node *p;
     p=list_head;
     while(p!=NULL)
     {
                   puts(p->name);
                   printf("%d\n",p->age); //and here
                   p=p->next;
                   }
}
```

Note that you have been trying to access a struct element without pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `age=data2;` by `neos->age = data2;`

and replace `printf("%d\n",age);` by  `printf("%d\n", p->age);`

There is no `age` variable, `age` is a member of `struct node`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared it in a structure so to access it you have to pass by your structure

```
neos->age
```

Answer (score 0):

age is just an element in a structure.

So assuming we have a structure defined as the following:

```
struct PlaceHolder {
    int int_element
    char char_element
} * place_holder;
```

to access any of the elements you need to access the structure first and reference the element in that structure.

```
place_holder->int_element = 5;
place_holder->char_element = "a";
```

In your case you have both `list_head` and `neos` as global variables, so to access an element in any of them you have to do:

```
list_head->age = data2;
neos->age = data2;
```